# JBoss configuration files

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I've inherited a project that is running a single instance of a JBoss 7.x server, java back-end, etc. I'm completely new to JBoss and I was curious about the configuration of the file structure(s), what I *have* to have and where. The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/config-files.html) has a different structure than what I've been handed and I'm not sure how one would, say, setup a completely new web application server project (i.e. starting a project from scratch).

Why, for instance, do I have multiple standalone.xml files? Namely,

```
standalone.xml
standalone-ha.xml
standalone-full-ha.xml
standalone-full.xml
```

Basically, I'm looking for a 'You NEED these to get your app running' sort of guide.

My JBoss folder has this structure

```
|--appclient
|  |--configuration
|  |  `--appclient.xml
|  |  `-- logging.properties
|
|--bin
|  |--client
|  |  `-- jboss-client.jar
|  |--init.d
|  |  `-- jboss-as.conf
|  |  `-- jboss-as-standalone.sh
|  `--(a lot of .bat and .conf files)
|  
|--bundles
|   |--javax
|   |  |--servlet
|   |    |--api
|   |       |--v25
|   |           `--jbosgi-http-api-1.0.5.jar
|   |--org
|      |--apache
|      |--jboss
|      |--osgi
|      |--projectodd
|  
|--docs
|  |--examples
|  |--schema
|  
|--domain
|  |--configuration
|  |  `--domain.xml
|  |  `--host.xml
|  |  `--host-master.xml
|  |  `--host-slave.xml
|  |--data
|  |  |--content
|  |     `--(empty)
|  |--tmp
|  |  |--auth
|  |     `--(empty)
|  
|--modules
|  |--asm
|  |  |--main
|  |     |--asm
|  |        `--asm-3.3.1.jar
|  |        `--module.xml
|  |--ch
|  |--com
|  |--gnu
|  |--javaee
|  |--javax
|  |--jline
|  |--net
|  |--nu
|  |--org
|  |--sun
|  
|--standalone
|  |--configuration
|  |  `--(I know the standalone.xml files go here)
|  |--data
|  |--deployments
|  |  `-- (I know the .war files go here)
|  |--lib
|  |--log
|  |  `-- (what ever could this be?? *sarcasm)
|  |--tmp
|  
|--welcome-content
```

*clearly I got tired and didn't label *everything* in every folder

Answer (score 3):

The link you provided is for an older version of jboss (4, 5), that is why it's all different jej

standalone*.xml specifies the services jboss provides to the user. You can choose the services you need, so you don't have to waste memory on services you are not going to use.

For example, standalone-full-ha.xml provides all services, and also starts jboss in a cluster mode. standalone-full has all the services, but without cluster mode. standalone.xml is the default one, and has all the basic services you will need to deploy an app (note that it does not include JMS support).

In the extension section of your standalone*.xml you can see what services are being provided.

When you start jboss, if you don't use the -c param, it will use standalone.xml. If you want to use standalone-full.xml (or any other config, could be a custom one), you would use `standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml`

As you said, standalone/deployments is where you deploy your apps. Remember to place a .dodeploy file to tell jboss to deploy your apps. For example, myExample.war should have a myExample.war.dodeploy (if you forget this, the log will tell you that there is an app to deploy, and is waiting for the dodeploy file)

Hope it helps!